# Magento error 'File size should be more than 0 bytes' when uploading product image

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and am currently building a local test site. I have got everything working fine but I am having trouble uploading product images in Magento. every time I try to upload I get **'File size should be more than 0 bytes'**

I have changed the permission on the media directory to 777
The only other changes I have have done is Skin and template changes. 
I am using IP instead of domain `http://10.1.1.143/magento/`

version is 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with your local path were the image is stored. I've had the problem too and found out that it can be overcome by:

- storing the images locally in a shorter path with less than 8 folder levels deep.
- make sure they're not on a substituted drive or network drive.

Simply putting them into "c:\images" has always worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Probably some thumbnails images with 0 byte.
This might be because of some space constraint.

Also check folder permissions.

Comment: The problem is uploading the file, if i try to upload I get the error, I have plenty of space, and the whole media directory is set to 777